# Select all rows with same IDs if one column contains a particular value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks roughly as follows:

```
Runners Leagues  Matches   Line   InDict

Team 1  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 1   'Yes'
Team 2  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 1   'Yes'
Team 3  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 1   'No'
Team 1  LeagueA  Match 4  Line 1   'Yes'
Team 2  LeagueA  Match 4  Line 1   'Yes'
Team 1  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 2   'Yes'
Team 2  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 2   'Yes'
Team 3  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 2   'Yes'
Team 1  LeagueB  Match 5  Line 8   'No'
Team 2  LeagueB  Match 5  Line 8   'Yes'
```

What I would like to do is select all rows where the Leagues/Matches/Line columns are the same if one of those rows contains the value 'No' in the InDict column.  So in the above example, the query would return:

```
Team 1  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 1   'Yes'
Team 2  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 1   'Yes'
Team 3  LeagueA  Match 1  Line 1   'No'
Team 1  LeagueB  Match 5  Line 8   'No'
Team 2  LeagueB  Match 5  Line 8   'Yes'
```

I'm new to mysql, so I'm struggling to find the correct query for this purpose.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows you to use multiple columns subqueries in `in` operator:

```
select *
from TableName
where (Leagues,Matches,Line) in (
    select Leagues,Matches,Line
    from TableName
    where InDict='''No'''
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddf5c/1

Comment: Although it seems tautologous, in addition to the PK which must exist on (runners,leagues,matches,line), this query will greatly benefit from a key on (leagues,matches,line,indict)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select * from tableName a where 
exists(select * from tableName b where 
b.league=a.league and 
b.matches=a.matches and 
b.line=a.line and 
b.inDict="No")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from yourtable
where concat(leagues,Matche,line) in(
    select concat(leagues,Matche,line) as v
    from yourtable
    where InDict = 'No'
)
```

Comment: Well, it's wrong and to my mind unhelpful. The other answers have the advantage of being correct.

Comment: It's easy to say _'It's wrong'_. but please explain which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: No. You've said that you've tested it already, so let's see that. I'll give you your point back, and a bonus point too.

Comment: I think you don't need sqlfiddle to explain which part of my code is wrong. And so do i, i don't need to prove that my code is works. Because you can read it. Only six line of code, and you didn't know that it's work or not?

Comment: OK. 1. This query is wrong. There is no way that it can generate the desired result. I can see that. I don't have to test it. So when you say you have tested it, I find that a little disingenuous. 2. Case sensitivity has no bearing on this problem. 3. To a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which CONCAT need play any part in the solution. We're all here to learn. I get that. But what can we learn from this answer?

Comment: What i mean in case sensitive is `where InDict = 'No'` are different from `where InDict = 'nO'`. i wanna ask. did `concat(a,b) = concat(x,y)` equal with `a=x and b=y` in sql which a,b,x,y are string?

Comment: In general, there is no difference between between 'no', 'No' 'nO', and 'NO'. Any difference would be entirely dependent upon the collation used. The default collation is case insensitive. And no, concat(a,b) = concat(x,y) will not necessarily be the same as a=x and b=y. Consider the example of x = 1234, y=56, a=123, b=456.